# Unexpected times in systemctl list-timers for fstrim.timer

Tags: systemd

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 and I was checking whether fstrim was enabled in my system and found this when running `systemctl list-timers`:

```
NEXT                         LEFT       LAST                         PASSED       UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Mon 2018-10-01 00:00:00 -03  8h left    Wed 2018-09-26 15:19:43 -03  3 days ago   fstrim.timer                 fstrim.service
```

There are two weird things: I'm sure my computer was off in the afternoon on Wednesday and the next scheduled run is not a week later (this timer is supposed to run weekly), not even close.

How do I interpret this output and how do I know if fstrim is really running regularly?

Comment: Maybe it thinks of a week as a business week,i.e 5 days

Comment: I guess it was just a glitch (cmos battery failed on that boot or something like that). I won't worry much about it.